# Jqgrid data is correctly filtered but filter options are showing incorrect values

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.5.2.The filter options are not getting set correctly even if the data is filter successfully. Below is the function used to fetch filter data.

```
//retrieve the filter data from the HttpSession in JSOn format successfully.
    function loadFilterData(){
        var postfiltRet={};
        var jsonStr = '';

         //Retrieve the filter data from the HttpSession Object in JSON format  and passs it to the grid.
         jq.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:8080/ui/paw/getstorefltrdata.raws",
             processData: false,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             type: 'POST',
             async:false,
             dataType : 'json'
         }).done(function(msgRec) {
                alert("Retrieved data from first call");
                if(msgRec==null && typeof msgRec == "object"){
                    alert("msgRec retrieved from session is null:" + msgRec);                       
                }
                else{
                    postfiltRet=msgRec;
                    jsonStr=JSON.stringify(postfiltRet);
                    alert("Data JSON:" +jsonStr);
                }

         });

       var queueStatus=jQuery('#queueStatus option:selected').val();
    finalUrl= "http://localhost:8080/ui/paw/loadworkflowqueuedata.raws?timezone="+&selRole="+ selectedRole+"&"+queueStatus;


    jq("#grid").jqGrid({       
     url:finalUrl,   
     ajaxGridOptions: {cache: false},//added the option to always reload the grid and not to cache the result.
     datatype: 'json',    
     mtype: 'GET', 
     colNames:[ 'Requestor Name'],       
     colModel:[
      {name:'requestor',index:'requestor',sortable: true, width:100,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'requestorRegion', index:'requestorRegion',sortable: true,width:65,editable:false, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:8, style: "height: 90%"}, stype:'select', edittype:'select',"searchoptions": {
              "value": ":All;Asia Pacific:Asia Pacific;Australia/NZ:Australia/NZ;Europe:Europe;Japan:Japan;Latin America:Latin America;North America:North America"
           }}
      ],
       postData: {     
       },    
       height: 'auto',       
       autowidth: true,    
       rownumbers: true,       
       pager: '#pager',       
       viewrecords: true,       
       sortorder: "asc",       
       emptyrecords: "Empty records",      
       loadonce: true,
       rowNum:20,
       ignoreCase: true,
       prmNames: {
           nd: null
       },   
       loadComplete: function() {

                var $this = jq(this);
              var postfilt = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
              alert("postfilt retrieved from the grid: " +JSON.stringify(postfilt));

              //store the filter data in the Java object and store the java object in Httpsession.
              if(typeof postfilt!='undefined'){
                  jq.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/ui/paw/storefltrdata.raws",
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: postfilt,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        async : false
                    }).done(function(msgRec) {
                    });
              }   
              else{
                  alert("postfilt1:" + postfilt);
              }

              //filter the data using the filters provided.This is working fine data is successfuly filtered but the combobox option of filter not //set correctly.
              if ($this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                          datatype: "local",
                          postData: { filters: postfilt},
                          search: true
                      });
                      $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: postpage}]);
                  }, 25);
              }

        },

       jsonReader : {    
           root: "rows",           
           repeatitems: false,
           page:"page",           
           total: "total",           
           records: "records", 
           cell: "cell",           
           id: "id"      
           }   
       });

     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false, refresh:true})
       .navButtonAdd('#pager',{caption:"Export All",buttonicon:"ui-icon-document",onClickButton: function(){window.open(excelUrl,'_self');},position:"last"});
     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn",ignoreCase: true });   


}
```

If i summarize the above steps

1.First I fetch the filters stored in the HttpSession object in JSON format.

**e.g. postfilt:{"groupOp":"AND","rules":{"field":"requestorRegion","op":"eq","data":"Europe"}]}**

2.Pass those filters to the grid so that they can be set in the Grid.

3.Filter the data of the grid as per the passed filter.

I don't understand why the data is filtered successfully but the filter options above the grid is not set correctly?Did I missed anything in filter setting or in grid definition? Please do let me know If you need more information or I missed anything.

Comment: Please if anybody could not understand the question. Just let me know. I will help you in understand the question.

Comment: can any body please help me with the above question please?